# Bokeh: The widths of vertical bars doesn't change

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I came across one problem I couldn't find a solution. I would like to change the bar width of my plot, but doesn't matter the number I put in the WIDTH parameter of the method vbar, the graph remains the same.

[The plot with WIDTH=100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlU5S.png)

[image]

[The plot with WIDTH=500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lildu.png)

[image]

[Apply Zoom is not a solution. The bar seems like a line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Otvu.png)

[image]

Here is the code:

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Data/moviments.txt', delimiter='\t', encoding='utf-8')

output_file("bar_basic.html")

df['DT']=pd.to_datetime(df['DT'])

p = figure(x_axis_type='datetime',
           plot_width=1230,
           plot_height=500,
           title='Moviments')

p.vbar(x=df['DT'],top=df['SUM_IN'], width=100, fill_alpha=0.8, color='green')
p.vbar(x=df['DT'],top=df['SUM_OUT'], width=100, fill_alpha=0.8, color='red')

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None

show(p)
```

That is the info of my dataframe:

> RangeIndex: 133 entries, 0 to
>   132 Data columns (total 5 columns): DT                133 non-null
>   datetime64[ns] TRANSACT_IN       133 non-null int64 TRANSACT_OUT
>   133 non-null int64 SUM_IN            133 non-null int64 SUM_OUT
>   133 non-null int64 dtypes: datetime64ns, int64(4)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The underlying scale on datetime axes is milliseconds-since-epoch. So, currently you are looking at bars 500ms wide across a scale of months. You need to make the bars ***much*** wider. For instance, a bar "one day" wide would need:

```
width=24*60*60*1000 # 86400000
```

Alternatively with recent Bokeh versions you can also use a [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), e.g.

```
width=timedelta(days=1)
```