# Bokeh Bar Chart not showing width properly

Tags: python, bokeh

This is what my x-axis looks like, it's the dataframe index:

```
overall_month.index.normalize().tolist()
```

Result:

```
[Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), Timestamp('2018-02-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), Timestamp('2018-03-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), Timestamp('2018-04-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), Timestamp('2018-05-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), Timestamp('2018-06-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), Timestamp('2018-07-01 00:00:00', freq='MS')]
```

I've got the bar chart being generated like this:

```
p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=400, x_axis_type="datetime")
p.vbar(x=overall_month.index, width=0.5, bottom=0,
   top=[1.2, 2.5, 3.7, 1.2, 2.5, 3.7], color="firebrick")
p.xaxis.formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter(years=['%Y-%m-%d'])
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = math.pi/2
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.y_range.start = 0
show(p)
```

However, the bar chart lines show up as one straight line with almost 0 width, how can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bokeh: The widths of vertical bars doesn't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50285405/bokeh-the-widths-of-vertical-bars-doesnt-change)

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of the linked question above, but in case it does not get moderated quickly (or ever), long story short: The units of a datetime axis are "milliseconds since epoch" so a width of 0.5 means a width of 0.5 milliseconds (on a scale of months). Hence, very narrow bars. You need to set a *much* bigger width.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!